# Rails 5.0.1 db:migrate - ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `ar_internal_metadata`

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I recently upgraded to Rails 5.0.1 from 4.2.x, and upon attempting a db:migrate I encountered an issue with ar_internal_metadata, which appears to be incompatible with MySQL5.

To reproduce (assuming a Rails 5 environment with gems installed and database schema in place):

1. Drop the ar_internal_metadata table from the development database (if it's there).
2. Run "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
3. Run it again.

On the second run (regardless of whether migrations are pending or not), this error is raised:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `ar_internal_metadata` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2017-04-30 20:49:17', '2017-04-30 20:49:17')

The ar_internal_metadata schema indicates to me that MySQL5 does seem to have a valid gripe:  The primary key field is set up as not null, but the default is null.  And, since it's a varchar(255) type, it can't auto-increment.  Apparently, the ActiveRecord machinery is not providing a value for 'key'.

```
mysql> desc ar_internal_metadata;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| key        | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| value      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Here are the contents of ar_internal_metadata just before the second call to db:migrate:

```
mysql> select * from ar_internal_metadata;
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| key | value | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|     | NULL  | 2017-04-30 20:56:39 | 2017-04-30 20:56:39 |
+-----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Has anyone seen this issue?  Any suggestions for workarounds or where to look?  What value should ActiveRecord be putting into ar_internal_metadata for 'key' (especially the second time db:migrate runs)?

Comment: This sounds more like it would be resolved with an [issue on github](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#reporting-an-issue) rather than a SO question.

Comment: Found it. The toxic combination is the ar_internal_metadata machinery and config/initializers/disable_mass_assignment.rb. disable_mass_assignment.rb consists of a single line:

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:attr_accessible, nil)